# Python mock access "real" objects while mocking a module

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock

Is it possible to access "real" objects while mocking a module? What I'm trying to do is mock some function, but throw "real" exceptions, like this:

```
@mock.patch('my_project.requests')
def test_foo(self,  mock_requests):

    mock_requests.post = mock.Mock(side_effect=requests.ConnectionError())

    thread = CommandThread("command", 3, 2, 0)
    thread.run() #this is were I exercise requests.post

    self.assert(thread.was_successful is False)
```

Inside my CommandThread I have a check like

```
try:
    requests.post(url, data=data)
except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout):
    self.was_successful = False
```

however, my test fails because the exception is not caught inside the try/except block (when I do like `except Exception:` it works)
The reason, I think, is simply because I mocked this "namespace" in my test case, so I actually raise `my_project.requests.ConnectionError` exception rather than proper, `requests.ConnectionError` from original package.
Is it somehow possible to access/throw "real" exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your mock is actually overwriting the entire requests module in your code. Here is how you can debug this:

In your code, add this:

```
try:
    requests.post('', data='')
except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout):
    was_successful = False
except Exception, err:
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
```

When you run the test, you will be dropped into the debugger so that you can take a look at what is happening. If we look at what you are catching, this is what we see:

```
(Pdb) requests.ConnectionError
<MagicMock name='requests.ConnectionError' id='4562438992'>
```

You are actually catching a mock ConnectionError because your mock patched out the entire requests module and you were feeding in a real requests error.

You can fix this by making your mock more specific and only overriding the post method on the requests module:

```
@mock.patch('my_project.requests.post')
def test_foo(self,  mock_requests):
    mock_requests.side_effect = requests.ConnectionError()
    ...
```